# 3DS Specifications List

Tags: nintendo-ds

Now that the 3DS launched on Japan, I was wondering if anybody knows if there's already been modders or enthusiasts that have done spec testing on the hardware.  I'd like to know how much potential power it packs! :D

Comment: Tech On! began disassembling a 3DS, which you can see here: http://techon.nikkeibp.co.jp/english/NEWS_EN/20110228/189942/ . Do note that part 2 of the article, where I presume they will do hardware spec testing of some sort, is not yet up.

Comment: WHOA, pretty awesome!  I'll keep a close eye on this page, seems they will have very extensive analysis of the 3DS when done. :D too bad I cant upvote your answer XD

Answer (score 2):

Answered as CW so others can edit.

Here are [some](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/09/nintendo-3ds-specs-leaked-dual-arm-processors/) [links](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/3DS-Zelda-Mario-Kart-Paper-Mario-animal-crossing,news-8154.html) that provide specs (c/p below):

the 3DS will have a pair of 266MHz ARM11 CPUs (yes, two of them), a 133MHz GPU with 4MB of dedicated VRAM, 64MB of regular RAM and 1.5GB flash storage.

Size (when closed):

Approximately 5.3-inches wide, 2.9-inches long, 0.8-inches tall.

Weight:

Approximately 8 ounces.

Top Screen:

3.53-inch widescreen LCD display, enabling 3D viewing without the need for special glasses; with 800 x 240 pixel resolution (400 pixels are allocated for each eye to enable 3D viewing).

ZoomCameras:

One inner camera and two outer cameras with 640 x 480 (0.3MP) pixel resolution.

Wireless Communication:

Can communicate in the 2.4 GHz band. Multiple Nintendo 3DS systems can connect via a local wireless connection to enable users to communicate or enjoy competitive gameplay. Systems also can connect to LAN access points to access the internet and enable people to enjoy games with others. Will support IEEE 802.11 with enhanced security (WPA/WPA2).

Game Controls:

Touch screen, embedded microphone, A/B/X/Y face buttons, +Control Pad. L/R buttons, Start and Select buttons, "Circle Pad" that allows 360-degree analog input, one inner camera, two outer cameras, motion sensor and gyro sensor.

Other Input Controls:

3D Depth Slider to adjust level of 3D effect (can be scaled back or turned off completely depending on the preference of the user) HOME button to call system function, Wireless switch to turn off wireless communications (even during gameplay), Power button.

Input/Output:

A game card slot, an SD memory card slot, an AC adapter connector, a charging cradle terminal and a stereo headphone output jack.

Sound:

Stereo speakers positioned to the left and right of the top screen.

Stylus:

The telescoping stylus is approximately 4 inches when fully extended.

Comment: Thanks for this, sorry I didn't specify I was concentrating more on processing and graphical specs XD although they are tied to the whole hardware itself.